# Using lodash cloneDeep() on mongoose result - can't update resulting JSON

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, lodash

Technologies in use:  Node.js, Express, Mongoose, Mocha, lodash

In testing my service, my app:

1. Gets a result from saving a new document using Mongoose
2. Uses lodash.cloneDeep() to clone the result
3. Tries to alter the content of the cloned instance

The result is that I get a cloned document that is in a really strange state.  When trying to modify the values, if I query the values of the specific objects that were changed, it shows the correct value.  However, when I just dump the document itself to the console, it is as if I hadn't  updated the values.  Likewise, if I pass the document into the save routine, it saves the document to MongoDb as if I hadn't changed any values.

Here is the code:

Test Code:

```
describe('### UPDATE ALARM', function () {
    it('Should save an alarm record for newly created asset', async () => {
        var asset = await Asset.findOne({ _id: compAdminAsset })
        const req = { user: { _id: compAdminId } }
        var alarm = await AlarmController.getByAsset(req, asset)
        expect(alarm._user).to.be.equal(compAdminId)
        expect(alarm._asset).to.be.equal(compAdminAsset)

        var newAlarm = _.cloneDeep(alarm)
        console.log('#### Newly Cloned Alarm Object')
        console.log(newAlarm)

        // change the rhSettings values
        newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmLow = true
        newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmHigh = true
        newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow = 40
        newAlarm.rhSettings.rhHigh = 85

        console.log()
        console.log('#### Cloned Alarm Object AFTER updating values')
        console.log(newAlarm)

        console.log()
        console.log('####  Directly query the values that were changed ')
        console.log('newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmLow: ' + newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmLow)
        console.log('newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmHigh: ' + newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmHigh)
        console.log('newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow: ' + newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow)
        console.log('newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow:  '+ newAlarm.rhSettings.rhHigh)

        var savedAlarm = await AlarmController.update(req, newAlarm)
        .
        .
        .
    })
})
```

Output from Test Code:

```
    ### UPDATE ALARM
#### Newly Cloned Alarm Object
{ rhSettings:
   { rhLow: 0, rhHigh: 80, rhAlarmLow: false, rhAlarmHigh: false },
  tempSettings:
   { tempLow: 50,
     tempHigh: 100,
     tempAlarmLow: false,
     tempAlarmHigh: false },
  _user: 'c86a7618-2323-48ec-b9e0-0d953301e37f',
  _asset: '6ca7a1ba-fc16-4cbf-9b4d-029c508d6b6c',
  _id: 5bde26a5038bec31683b8d80,
  createdAt: 2018-11-03T22:52:21.604Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-11-03T22:52:21.604Z,
  __v: 0 }

#### Cloned Alarm Object AFTER updating values
{ rhSettings:
   { rhLow: 0, rhHigh: 80, rhAlarmLow: false, rhAlarmHigh: false },
  tempSettings:
   { tempLow: 50,
     tempHigh: 100,
     tempAlarmLow: false,
     tempAlarmHigh: false },
  _user: 'c86a7618-2323-48ec-b9e0-0d953301e37f',
  _asset: '6ca7a1ba-fc16-4cbf-9b4d-029c508d6b6c',
  _id: 5bde26a5038bec31683b8d80,
  createdAt: 2018-11-03T22:52:21.604Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-11-03T22:52:21.604Z,
  __v: 0 }

#### Query the values that were changed directly
newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmLow: true
newAlarm.rhSettings.rhAlarmHigh: true
newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow: 40
newAlarm.rhSettings.rhLow:  85
```

Code that returns the "newAlarm" object:

```
const Model = require('../models/alarm.model')

exports.getByAsset = async function (req, asset) {
    let newAlarm = new Model()
    newAlarm._asset = asset._id
    newAlarm._user = req.user._id
    newAlarm.rhSettings = asset.rhSettings
    newAlarm.tempSettings = asset.tempSettings
    return await newAlarm.save()
}
```

Any ideas what is causing the cloned JSON object to be in this weird state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you would use in order to keep mongoose happy with change tracking etc would be using [**set**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set).

However I highly doubt cloning the object and using set would be something even remotely close to a best practice.

Why not simply create another model? Why circumventing the build in change tracking etc in mongoose by cloning?

You might as well simply use [toObject](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) of your new mongoose model ... skip the cloning ... change values etc ... then simply pass that object to a `new Model(yourObjectWithChanges)` and then save:

```
var newAlarm = alarm.toObject() 
... do your changes
let newAlarmModel = new Model(newAlarm)
await newAlarmModel.save()
```

Comment: Thanks @Akrion!   I removed the lodash cloneDeep() and just directly instantiated newAlarm as a new schema instance (newAlarm = new Alarm(alarm)) and it works perfectly now.  I didn't even need the alarm.toObject() line.